# Generate int4range from a set of integer values selecting as a specific table and column

Tags: postgresql, casting, range, lag, generate-series

I am trying to generate a set of `int4range` values, but instead of getting `int4range`, I'm getting type `record`. I can't seem to extract the range or cast to the range type.

I specifically want to keep the `SELECT "app_table"."id"` part of the sql, since I am trying to manipulate an ORM to map this to an application.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT "app_table"."id" FROM (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT (lag(a) OVER()), a, '[)'
            FROM generate_series(0, 10, 1)
            AS a OFFSET 1) AS id
) AS app_table LIMIT 3;
```

What I get:

```
     id (type of record)
------------------------
1    (0,1,"[)")
2    (1,2,"[)")
3    (2,3,"[)")
```

Another attempt:

```
SELECT "app_table"."id" FROM (
    SELECT (lag(id) OVER()), id, '[)'
        FROM generate_series(0, 10, 1)
        AS id OFFSET 1
) AS app_table
```

What I get:

```
     id (type of integer)
------------------------
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
     id (type of int4range)
---------------------------
1    [0,1)
2    [1,2)
3    [2,3)
```

I'm sure this is something simple, and I've tried lots of variations, but I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT "app_table"."id"
FROM  (
   SELECT int4range(a, a+1) AS id
   FROM   generate_series(0, 2) a
   ) app_table;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=54d4d8664db78e5e870b49cf79132364)*

Produces your desired result.

To generate the type `int4range` from `integer`, use the corresponding function `int4range()`.
Read the manual about [*Constructing Ranges and Multiranges*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT).

You already got that right with a table alias:

> I specifically want to keep the `SELECT "app_table"."id"` part of the sql

Comment: I appreciate your time, but i know the fundamentals of using generate_series. As mentioned, I specifically want to `SELECT "app_table"."id" FROM`. This is because (I failed to mention) I'm mapping to an ORM that doesn't currently have support for generate_series, and while I can easily modify the internal part, I can't easily modify that first part of the sql. Hope that makes sense and you might be able to help me achieve this.

Comment: It was my fault for not being clear enough with the background of what I'm trying to do. Again, thank you, and I hope it makes sense and is something achievable.

Comment: @djangomachine: The missing bit in your question is neither about `generate_series()`, nor the table alias, but the correct construction of `int4range` types.